# ¿Cómo ejecutar sentencia curl con Volley en Android Studio?

Tags: android, curl, android-volley

Estoy usando la API openfoodfacts, e intentando subir una imagen por POST con Volley. Logro hacerlo con éxito desde Windows CMD pero no desde Android Studio. Este es el código que uso del consola de windows:

```
curl --user on:on --form "imgupload_front=@C:\Users\franc\Desktop\calamares.jpg" --form code=8411916819976 --form imagefield=front --form user_id=user --form password=pass https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/cgi/product_image_upload.pl
```

Cuando lo pruebo en android utilizo la ruta: `Memoria interna\DCIM\Screenshots\a.jpg`.

```
String URL = "https://fr.openfoodfacts.net/cgi/product_image_upload.pl";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("Check Response",response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Check Error","Error");
                }
            }
    ){
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            return new byte[]{};

        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
            map.put("imgupload_front", "@Memoria interna\\DCIM\\Screenshots\\a.jpg");
            map.put("code", code);
            map.put("imagefield","front");
            map.put("user_id",id);
            map.put("password",pass);
            return map;
        }
    };
    request.setRetryPolicy(new
 DefaultRetryPolicy(15000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES));
        queue.add(request);
```

El error que me arroja es: `{"error":"Aucun code-barres spécifié ou trouvé dans l'image ou le nom du fichier.","status":"status not ok","files":[{"filename":"","error":"Aucun code-barres spécifié ou trouvé dans l'image ou le nom du fichier."}]}`

No deja subir la misma imagen, y voy haciendo capturas de pantallas. Aún así, lo puedo hacer desde la CMD pero no desde android. También he probado a ejecutar el comando curl en línea y me da el mismo error que en android. El código existe, es el mismo en todas las pruebas.

¿Alguna manera de ejecutar la sentencia curl desde android?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La petición cURL parece estar siendo enviada, pero el servidor te está devolviendo un error, según el cual esa imagen no es aceptada por algún motivo. Quizá conviene revisar los requisitos de ese servidor para subir imágenes.

Answer (score 1):

Para subir una imagen a la API OpenFoodFacts utilizando Volley en Android Studio, debes seguir los siguientes pasos:

Agrega la dependencia de Volley en tu archivo build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

Crea una instancia de RequestQueue y una instancia de ImageRequest. La RequestQueue se encargará de enviar la petición, y el ImageRequest se encargará de procesar la respuesta.

```
// Crea una instancia de RequestQueue
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

// Crea una instancia de ImageRequest
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(
    "https://tu-imagen.com/imagen.jpg",
    new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
        // Procesa la respuesta aquí
      }
    },
    0, // Ancho
    0, // Alto
    ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP,
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // Procesa el error aquí
      }
    }
);
```

Agrega la petición a la RequestQueue para que se envíe a la API OpenFoodFacts.

```
// Agrega la petición a la RequestQueue
queue.add(request);
```

Con esto, ya deberías poder subir una imagen a la API OpenFoodFacts utilizando Volley en Android Studio.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Pero, en tu respuesta no estás especificando a qué código de producto le cambias la imagen. ¿Podrías hacer esa aclaración?

Answer (score -1):

Lo primero que tienes que saber es que Volley no te permite usar comandos curl directamente. En su lugar, puedes usar Volley para hacer solicitudes HTTP de una manera similar a como lo haría curl.

La forma en que defines la solicitud HTTP dependerá de los parámetros que quieras enviar con la solicitud. En tu caso, estás usando varios parámetros (como "code" y "user_id") y también estás enviando un archivo de imagen. Para enviar un archivo de imagen con Volley, puedes usar una clase como MultipartRequest.

Un ejemplo de cómo usar esta clase para hacer una solicitud HTTP con Volley podría ser el siguiente:

```
// Creamos una nueva cola de solicitudes
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

// Creamos una nueva solicitud Multipart
MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest(
  Request.Method.POST,
  "https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/cgi/product_image_upload.pl",
  new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
      // Procesamos la respuesta aquí
    }
  },
  new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      // Procesamos el error aquí
    }
  }
);

// Agregamos los parámetros que queremos enviar con la solicitud
request.addParameter("code", code);
request.addParameter("imagefield", "front");
request.addParameter("user_id", id);
request.addParameter("password", pass);

// Agregamos el archivo de imagen a la solicitud
request.addFile("imgupload_front", "Memoria interna\\DCIM\\Screenshots\\a.jpg");

// Enviamos la solicitud a la cola
queue.add(request);
```

Ten en cuenta que la ruta que estás usando para acceder a la imagen en tu dispositivo ("Memoria interna\DCIM\Screenshots\a.jpg") puede no ser válida. Es posible que necesites usar una ruta diferente para acceder a la imagen en tu dispositivo.

Comment: Hola, Cristian. Gracias por responder, pero no me sirve este código. No especifica la dependecia a añadir para utilizar MulitpartRequest. La he buscado he Maven, y solicita implementar métodos. A pesar de añadir los métodos aparecen errores en rojo y no deja compilar. ¿Puedes añadir la dependencia a añadir y métodos a implementar?